# C++: How to remove all occurrences of a value in a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm currently trying to study how linked lists work in C++, and I've come across the topic of removing a certain value in the linked list. I understand how to remove the first instance of a particular value, and there's no problem there. However, I cannot wrap my mind around how to remove all instances of some value in a linked list. I can see how I would remove any instance of the value at the beginning and middle of the list, but then I get stuck once l->next is a nullptr. If l->next is a nullptr, then how would I redirect the pointer from before the value to something after the value that is to be removed?

I apologize if this is a repeated question; I will remove it if that is the case.

Comment: Without knowing anything about your implementation and only guessing from the very limited information you have given us to your code, you could keep a pointer to the previous node in a separate variable.

Comment: Actually, I'm not implementing this remove function; I'm just wondering how to remove a node that is at the end of a linked list.

Comment: You do it the same way: keep track of the *previous* node.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove a node you indeed nullify it's pointer, so in order to be able to keep iterating the list, you save the next pointer before the removal:

```
while(node->next != node_I_want_to_remove){
    node = node->next;
}

Node* tmp = node->next->next; // save the next
remove(node->next);  
node->next = tmp;             // attach the two ends of the list and keep iterating
```